# Creating Activity Stream in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I need to generate a User Stream. I am using Content Type Framework in Django 1.5 and i am using third party packages 'Phileo(for liking),Django-Posts(for Post),Dialogos(comments)

I have a Post,Comment,Like,Share,Connection along with Event Database Models

Here is what my Post Model look like

```
class Post(models.Model):
      text = models.TextField(_("Text"))
      .... # no GenericForeignKey
```

Here is my Comments Model

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.IntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()

    comment = models.TextField()
```

Here is my UserEvent Model

```
class UserEvent(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    data_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, null=True)
    data_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    data_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('data_type', 'data_id')


class Event(models.Model):
    eventId = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="untitled")
```

The UserEvent contains all the activity of a User like (loggedIn,loggedOut,SignUp,Create Post,Comment on Post,Like a Post etc).

**Q--1** **What will be the best way to create a activity stream out of it.**

If i do something like `feeds = UserEvents.object.all()` and in template i can do..

```
{% for item in feeds%}
     {% if item.data_type.name == 'post' %}
         {{ item.data_object.text }}
         <!-- Show post -->
     {% endif %}
     {% if item.data_type.name == 'connection' %}
         <!-- Show User 3 and User 5 are now friend -->
     {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But the problem is `Post` has no foreign key to `Comments` Model.

**Q--2** So how can i show Comments related to the Post. I really dont want to use '***Template Tags***'. The other workaround is that i put `comments = generic.GenericRelation(Comment)` in Post Model but i want to be generic(and i believe UserEvent have all related items) because In future i have some more models .. like 'Share','Tag','Likes' etc.. THen do i need to put all generic relation in my POST.

```
class Like(models.Model):

    sender = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="liking")

    receiver_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    receiver_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    receiver = generic.GenericForeignKey(
        ct_field="receiver_content_type",
        fk_field="receiver_object_id"
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to do it all in the models.  I create a method in the user model like:

```
class UserEvent(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    data_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, null=True)
    data_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    data_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('data_type', 'data_id')


  def record_event(self, event, obj):

       UserEvent.objects.create(user=self, event=event, data_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj), data_id=obj.id)
```

Then in the save method of other models:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    # only record on creating a new post
    if not self.id:
        self.user.record_event(self.user, event=<not sure where you event from>, )

    super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This can be  made more sophisticated with a content type field in the activity log.
One of the benefits of this approach is it makes testing much easier as you can just test the model without having to also test views.

Comment: ok.. i am saving the UserEvent already.. the problem is how to get comments out of it and keep it generic.. see my template.. UserEvent is working for me but i dont know how to get data out of it..

Comment: The UserEvent is already recording activity of a User like (loggedIn,loggedOut,SignUp,Create Post,Comment on Post,Like a Post etc). You see Post have no foreign key to Comments,Likes,etc so how do i include them while querying UserEvent ?

Comment: This may be what you were refering to in Q2, but can you create a @property in Post like def comments(self): return list of comments related to this post from generic relation..  and do the same for Article etc.?  Somewhere a definition of how to get the comments for each is going to have to be done...

Comment: So can i do `{% for item in item.data_object.comments.all %}` if i define `def comments(self):` in **Post Model**

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons to create relationships between the models in a django app is to aid efficiency in retrieving those models with queries.

> **Q--1** *What will be the best way to create a activity stream out of it.*

The `UserEvent` model neatly encapsulates this behaviour of your app.

The snippet shown looks pretty good, it would also be possible to move the conditional into another template, which would allow it to be reused it in other parts of the site.

Something like:

```
 {% for item in feeds%}
     {% include "display_feed.html" %}
 {% endfor %}
```

**display_feed.html:**

```
 {% if item.data_type.name == 'post' %}
     {{ item.data_object.text }}
     <!-- Show post -->
 {% endif %}
 {% if item.data_type.name == 'connection' %}
     <!-- Show User 3 and User 5 are now friend -->
 {% endif %}
```

> **Q-2** *But the problem is Post has no foreign key to Comments Model.*

I'm not completely sure about the structure of your site, but I would suggest creating the `ForeignKey` the other way from `Comment` to `Post`.

Something like:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.IntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)        

    comment = models.TextField()
```

This then allows all the comments for a given post to retrieved, as they are [related-objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects):

```
post_comments = Post.comment_set.all()
```

If the `Comment` objects can be about more than just `Posts`, then this could be made into a generic relation.

All your future models 'Share', 'Tag', 'Likes', etc, can also have the same foreignkey and can be accessed in the same way. This also works in templates:

```
{% for item in post.comment_set.all %}
    {% include "display_comment.html" %}
{% end for %} 
{% for item in post.tag_set.all %}
    {% include "display_tag.html" %}
{% end for %}
```

IMHO the `UserEvent` model does not relate to the activity of retrieving comments so does not have to be used here. 
This may seem like a slightly simplistic answer, but often in django the simple answers are the most efficient, quickest to implement and best, ;).

Comment: I have other Models like Articles, Gallery, Images too.. I am using ContentType in all of them to make things generic.. Like `content_type = 'Image' object_id = 'image_id', content_type='Video' object_id ='video_id'` so adding foreign key to post will not make sense..

Comment: I added the `ForeignKey` to `Comment` _not_ `Post`.

Comment: do i need to add `ForeignKey` to `Comment` in my `Article, Gallery, Videos` Models too ?

Comment: Well, each `Comment` object is created about one of those objects and this needs to be represented in the `Comment` model. Is this what the `content_object` field represents? In which case a reverse lookup on this field will give you comments about the given object.